# How to do a matching with the Mahalanobis distance in with the Matching package

Tags: r, matching, mahalanobis

I want to do a matching with the Matching-package. Of course, I have the treatment variable which is the first matching criterion. Then I have the second variable (C) which should be considered for the matching using the Mahalanobis distance. The last two variables (D and E) should be matched exactly. Additionally, I have a matrix (R) that contains some exceptions, that must not matched.

```
Y <- cbind(Sample$A)
Tr <- cbind(Sample$B)
X <- cbind(Sample$C, Sample$D, Sample$E)

Matching_out <- Match(Y = Y, Tr = Tr, X = X, M = 2, replace = TRUE, ties = TRUE,
                  exact=c(0,1,1), restrict = R, Weight = 2)
summary(Matching_out)

MatchBalance(Tr ~ X, match.out = Matching_out, nboots = 1000, data = Sample)
```

I used "Weight = 2" in the formula because in the package description it says that this is the mahalanobis distance. But there is no difference in the case that I include this part to the code or not.

Does anyone knows how to do this matching with Mahalanobis distance for variable C and excat matching for variables D and E?

Also, does anyone knows what kind of matching this function uses, if I skip this part ("Weight = 2") in the function? Is it full matching, genetic matching, nearest neighbor matching? Or maybe what kind of distance the matching uses for the variable C?

Thank you

Comment: Mahalanobis versus inverse variance differ only when you have more than one continuous variable. In your example, the measures are identical, since you are doing exact matching on two of the variables. This function performs nearest neighbor matching by default, but has a number of flexible options to extend beyond a simple nearest neighbor, such as calipers and exact matching. The package is well documented, so starting with reading through `?Match` is a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already read the package description but I can't find anything about the default settings. How do you know that it is nearest neighbor matching? And if I want to add another continuous variable, how can I use the Mahalanobis distance? Is "Weight = 2" the right way to do it?

Comment: Yes, setting weight to 2 will do it. The Description section of the help page for `Match` oulines the types of matching the function implements ("including propensity score, Mahalanobis and inverse variance matching" as well as "exact and caliper" matching tools). It also mentions a second function, GenMatch, which performs genetic matching. If you are interested in the full match, it is available in the `optmatch` package.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't get the difference between nearest neighbor matching and Mahalanobis matching. Is nearest neighbor matching the type of matching the function uses and the Mahalanobis distance the distance measure that specifies the maximum distance that the nearest neighbor can take? For example when the nearest neighbor is not within this Mahalanobis distance there is no matching and the process continues until there is a possible match within the Mahalanobis distance. And if there is no possible match within this distance at all there will be no matching for this case, right?

Comment: Mahalanobis is a method to measure distance that removes correlation between variables and standardizes them. The inverse variance distance only performs the standardization. Either of these can be used as the distance to determine the n nearest neighbors. Including all neighbors within a particular distance is referred to as a caliper. It may be useful to read Rosenbaum and Rubin 1985. It is short and contains both of these methods if I remember correctly.